# State is updating, but the component is not sending updated state within the props to the child component in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I've created 4 components, `SalesBanner` which is parent of `ProductImagePanel`.`ProductImagePanel` is parent of `ProductCarouselProgressbar`. And `ProductCarouselProgressbar` is parent of `ProgressBar`.

So it's like

```
     SalesBanner
          |
          v
  ProductImagePanel
          |
          v
ProductCarouselProgressBar
          |
          v
     ProgressBar
```

I've state in `SalesBanner` component, which is passed down to all of its child components as props. Besides, I've also defined a function in `SalesBanner`, which is updating the state, and then sending back the updated states to its child components, as they are being re-rendered on invoking `setState()`.

**Problem is, states are updating in the `SalesBanner` but they are not passing down (updated) to its child component.**

Here's the code:

```
class SaleBanner extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            numberOfProductsOnSale: 4,
            productCategories: [  ...  ],
            productNames: [  ...  ],
            productPrice: {
                oldPrice: [  ...  ],
                salePrice: [  ...  ]
            },
            productImage: [  ...  ],
            currentlyRenderedProductId: 1  //This is what i want to update
        }

        this.updateCurrentProductRenderedId = this.updateCurrentProductRenderedId.bind(this);
    }

    //This function will update the state, and I want to pass its reference down to the child components
    updateCurrentProductRenderedId(newId) {
        this.setState(() => ({
            currentlyRenderedProductId: newId
        }))
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <SalesBanner>
                <ProductDetails category={this.state.productCategories[this.state.currentlyRenderedProductId]} prodName={this.state.productNames[this.state.currentlyRenderedProductId]} prodOldPrice={this.state.productPrice.oldPrice[this.state.currentlyRenderedProductId]} prodSalePrice={this.state.productPrice.salePrice[this.state.currentlyRenderedProductId]} />
                <ProductImagePanel updateState={this.updateCurrentProductRenderedId} numberOfProducts={this.state.numberOfProductsOnSale} currProductId={this.state.currentlyRenderedProductId} prodImage={this.state.productImage[this.state.currentlyRenderedProductId]}/>
                <ProductCarouselController />
            </SalesBanner>
        );
    }
}
```

`ProductImagePanel` Component Code:

```
class ProductImagePanel extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            numberOfProductsOnSale: props.numberOfProducts,
            currentlyRenderedProductId: props.currProductId,
            productImage: props.prodImage
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SaleProductImage>
                <ProductImageRendering />
                <ProductCarouselProgressbar updateState={this.props.updateState} numberOfProducts={this.state.numberOfProductsOnSale} currProductId={this.state.currentlyRenderedProductId} prodImage={this.state.productImage}/>
            </SaleProductImage>
        )
    }
}
```

`ProductCarouselProgressBar` Component Code:

```
class ProductCarouselProgressbar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            numberOfProductsInSale: props.numberOfProducts,
            currentProductId: props.currProductId,
            productImage: props.prodImage
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ProductIdAndProgressPanel>
        
                <CurrentId> { this.state.currentProductId < 9 ? '0' + this.state.currentProductId : this.state.currentProductId } </CurrentId>
                <ProgressBar currentProdId={this.state.currentProductId} updateState={this.props.updateState} />
                <TotalId> { this.state.numberOfProductsInSale < 9 ? '0' + this.state.numberOfProductsInSale : this.state.numberOfProductsInSale } </TotalId>
        
            </ProductIdAndProgressPanel>
        )
    }
}
```

`ProgressBar` Component Code:

```
class ProgressBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.progressBar = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.progressBar.current.style['width'] = (this.progressBar.current.offsetWidth + 1) + 'px';

            if(this.progressBar.current.offsetWidth > this.progressBar.current.parentNode.offsetWidth) {
                this.progressBar.current.style['width'] = 0;
                this.props.updateState(((this.props.currentProdId % 4 )) + 1);    //This is where I want to update state of the SalesBanner Component
            }
        }, 20);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <OuterProgressBar>
                <InnerProgressBar ref={this.progressBar}/>
            </OuterProgressBar>
        );
    }
}
```

Any other JSX syntax, which is not explained by me is either a React Component, or a styled-components tags.

Comment: I think what you are asking it how to propagate state values to top level or parent components and not downwards? or rather updating parent component states from child components.

Comment: @Xixis. No he is already able to accomplish that with his current code. The problem is that his child components are not re-rendering with the updated state-value in the parent.

Comment: @S. Joshi. Just wrote an answer for you which I think solves the root of your problem. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass down props to your child component it does not intuitively re-update you child's component state for you. If you want to do that, you need to make use of `componentDidUpdate()`

```
class ProductImagePanel extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        numberOfProductsOnSale: props.numberOfProducts,
        currentlyRenderedProductId: props.currProductId,
        productImage: props.prodImage
    };
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
   if(prevProps.currProductId !== this.props.currProductId){
       this.setState({
            numberOfProductsInSale: this.props.numberOfProducts,
            currentlyRenderedProductId: this.props.currProductId,
            productImage: this.props.prodImage
       })
   }
}

render() {
    return (
        <SaleProductImage>
            <ProductImageRendering />
            <ProductCarouselProgressbar updateState={this.props.updateState} numberOfProducts={this.state.numberOfProductsOnSale} currProductId={this.state.currentlyRenderedProductId} prodImage={this.state.productImage}/>
        </SaleProductImage>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The value is not updating, because you are saving the props values in state of each component, remove the state inside child components and access the values directly from props.

ProductImagePanel

```
class ProductImagePanel extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <SaleProductImage>
        <ProductImageRendering />
        <ProductCarouselProgressbar
          updateState={this.props.updateState}
          numberOfProducts={this.props.numberOfProducts}
          currProductId={this.props.currProductId}
          prodImage={this.props.productImage}
        />
      </SaleProductImage>
    );
  }
}
```

ProductCarouselProgressbar

```
class ProductCarouselProgressbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ProductIdAndProgressPanel>
        <CurrentId>
          {' '}
          {this.props.currProductId < 9
            ? '0' + this.props.currProductId
            : this.props.currProductId}{' '}
        </CurrentId>
        <ProgressBar
          currentProdId={this.props.currProductId}
          updateState={this.props.updateState}
        />
        <TotalId>
          {' '}
          {this.props.numberOfProducts < 9
            ? '0' + this.props.numberOfProducts
            : this.props.numberOfProducts}{' '}
        </TotalId>
      </ProductIdAndProgressPanel>
    );
  }
}
```

ProgressBar

```
class ProgressBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.progressBar = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.progressBar.current.style['width'] =
        this.progressBar.current.offsetWidth + 1 + 'px';

      if (
        this.progressBar.current.offsetWidth >
        this.progressBar.current.parentNode.offsetWidth
      ) {
        this.progressBar.current.style['width'] = 0;
        this.props.updateState((this.props.currProductId % 4) + 1); //This is where I want to update state of the SalesBanner Component
      }
    }, 20);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <OuterProgressBar>
        <InnerProgressBar ref={this.progressBar} />
      </OuterProgressBar>
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-r3cwjy)